# How to get request queue from New Relic in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, newrelic

Is there a way to get the real time request queue time from New Relic in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set up a header in your front end server so that New Relic will keep track of the amount of time from when the request reaches your front-end server through the moment the request reaches your application server. See this doc for more details: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/features/request-queuing-and-tracking-front-end-time.